# JavaFX Application Thread - java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

Tags: java, javafx

I am working in project where I was forced to create an alert when the user left the text field empty or when the input does not stasifiying the condition but it look that the condition for empty field does not work as seen on this [capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxFNQ.png).

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
   java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
   at math.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
   at math.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
...
```

---

This is the code:

```
class Main extends Application 
{
       
        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage1) throws Exception
       {
           Label lbl1= new Label("Note Controle");
           lbl1.setFont(new Font(15));
           TextField nc= new TextField();
           //...
        }

        @Override 
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            float c,td, mg;
            c=Float.parseFloat(nc.getText());
            td=Float.parseFloat(ntd.getText());
            if ((!nc.getText().isEmpty()&&nc.getText()!= null) &&
                (!ntd.getText().isEmpty()&&ntd.getText()!=null)) 
            {
                if ((c >= 0 && 20 >= c) && (td >= 0 && 20 >= td) ) 
                {
                    mg = (float) (c * 0.6 + td *         0.2);//examen60%td20% 
                    res.setText(String.valueOf(mg));
                } 
                else 
                {
                     //...
                }
             }
         }
   //...
}
```

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem you're having. Also, is there a reason you're using a `Stage` for your alerts instead of the built-in `Alert` API?

Comment: nc is empty and cannot be parsed to a float.

Comment: @Zephyr the same error as appear even after using alert api and change my code

Comment: @dan1st i dont get you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know why, but you correctly check for empty strings and just before that invoke this:

```
c  = Float.parseFloat(nc.getText());
td = Float.parseFloat(ntd.getText());
```

Which will throw the exception if `nc` or `ntd` hold empty strings, indeed.

Change it to, for example:

```
c  = Float.parseFloat(nc.getText().isEmpty() ? "0" : nc.getText());
td = Float.parseFloat(ndt.getText().isEmpty()? "0" : ntd.getText());
```

---

As a suggestion, this would be a better approach (*as it handles null + empty + nonNumeric values*).

```
public static boolean isNumeric(final String str) 
{
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) 
        return false;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) 
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

So:

```
c  = Float.parseFloat(!isNumeric(nc.getText()) ? "0" : nc.getText());
td = Float.parseFloat(!isNumeric(ndt.getText())? "0" : ntd.getText());
```

Comment: i have used the first affectation to do some calculation later if the empty condition go false

Comment: You're welcome @MXTV! Glad to help mate; )

Comment: i have question for you do you now some good ressource to learn javafx

Comment: I really don't know sh** of JavaFX to be sincere mate. Really, never touched it. : _ )